# Get and Set Text Content from a JSON Object using JavaScript in node.js

Tags: javascript, xml, json, parsing, node.js

Background information: I'm using node.js and this is a server side script.

That being said, here's the problem. I have a JSON Object `result`, when using `eyes.inspect()`, looks like

```
{
user: [
    {
        foods: {
            food: [
                {
                    #: 'McDonalds',
                    @: { type: 'string' }
                },
                {
                    #: 'Seafood Topped Salmon',
                    @: { type: 'string' }
                }
            ]
        },
        email: '****@******.edu',
        name: 'Leo'
    },
    {
        email: '****@******.edu',
        food-list: {
            food: [
                {
                    #: 'KFC',
                    @: { type: 'string' }
                },
                {
                    #: 'KGC',
                    @: { type: 'string' }
                }
            ]
        },
        name: 'Eric'
    }
]
}
```

When calling `console.log(result.user[0].foods.food[1])`, the output is `{ '#': 'Seafood Topped Salmon', '@': { type: 'string' } }`

So is there a way to get and set the text content of a node just like `Seafood Topped Salmon` and get rid of the type attribute?

Some more information: that JSON is actually parsed from an XML document. In the original xml file, the food node looks like `<food type="string">McDonalds</food>`. I must keep the `type="string"` attribute and after I'm done with editing the JSON object, I will parse it back to xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly access the text of that embedded object to get and set it as:

```
result.user[0].foods.food[1]['#']
```